Authentication in Microservice
I have 2 microservices Auth-manager and Gateway, Auth-manager has 1 entity as UserInfo(name, password and roles), 1 repository as UserInfoRepo have method List findRolesByUsername and 3 services (AuthService, CustomUserDetailService and JwtService), also 1 controller(AuthController).
Similarly, Gateway microservice has: 2 filters(AuthenticationFilter and RouteValidator), 1 util class(JwtUtil) and 1 externalService(Auth_Manager_service) for communication purpose.
AuthService:
@Service
public class AuthService {
    @Autowired
    private UserInfoRepository repository;
    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    @Autowired
    private JwtService jwtService;
    public String saveUser(UserInfo userInfo) {
        userInfo.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(userInfo.getPassword()));
        repository.save(userInfo);
        return "User added to the system!!!!";
    }
    public String generateToken(String username) {
        return jwtService.generateToken(username);
    }
    public void validateToken(String token) {
        jwtService.validateToken(token);
    }
    public List<String> getRolesByName(String username) {
        List<String> role = this.repository.findRolesByUsername(username).orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("No Role found for User: "+ username));
        return role;
    }
}

CustomUserDetailService:
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService{
    @Autowired
    private UserInfoRepository userInfoRepository;
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Optional<UserInfo> info = userInfoRepository.findByName(username);
        return info.map(CustomUserDetails::new).orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found with name :" + username));
    }
}

JwtService:
@Service
public class JwtService {
    public static final String SECRET = "..........";
    public void validateToken(final String token) {
        Jwts.parserBuilder().setSigningKey(getSignKey()).build().parseClaimsJws(token);
    }
    public String generateToken(String userName) {
        Map<String, Object> claims = new HashMap<>();
        return createToken(claims, userName);
    }
    private String createToken(Map<String, Object> claims, String userName) {
        return Jwts.builder()
                .setClaims(claims)
                .setSubject(userName)
                .setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000 * 60 * 30))
                .signWith(getSignKey(), SignatureAlgorithm.HS256).compact();
    }
    private Key getSignKey() {
        byte[] keyBytes = Decoders.BASE64.decode(SECRET);
        return Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(keyBytes);
    }
}

AuthController:
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/auth/v1")
@SecurityRequirement(name= "AuthSecurity")
public class AuthController {
    @Autowired
    private AuthService service;
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager manager;
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthController.class);
    @PostMapping("/register")
    public String addNewUser(@RequestBody UserInfo user) {
        return service.saveUser(user);
    }
    @PostMapping("/token")
    public String getToken(@RequestBody AuthRequest authRequest) {
        Authentication authenticate = manager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authRequest.getUserName(), authRequest.getPassword()));
        if (authenticate.isAuthenticated()) {
            return this.service.generateToken(authRequest.getUserName());
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("!!Invalid User!!");
        }
    }
    @GetMapping("/validate")
    public String validateToken(@RequestParam("token") String token) {
        service.validateToken(token);
        return "Token is valid";
    }
    @GetMapping("/getRolesByUsername")
    public List<String> getRolesByUsername(@RequestParam("username") String username){
        logger.info("Received request to get roles for username: {}", username);
        System.out.println("Received request to get roles for username: {}"+ username);
        System.out.println("Roles retrieved: "+ service.getRolesByName(username));
        logger.info("Roles retrieved for username {}: {}", username, service.getRolesByName(username));
        return service.getRolesByName(username);    
    }
}

Similarly Gateway microservice has: 2 filters(AuthenticationFilter and RouteValidator), 1 util class(JwtUtil) and 1 externalService(Auth_Manager_service) for communication purpose
AuthenticationFilter:
@Component
public class AuthenticationFilter extends AbstractGatewayFilterFactory<AuthenticationFilter.Config>{
    @Autowired
    private RouteValidator routeValidator;
    @Autowired
    private JwtUtil jwtUtil;
    private Auth_Manager_Service authManagerFeignClient;
    public AuthenticationFilter(@Lazy Auth_Manager_Service authManagerFeignClient) {
        super(Config.class);
        this.authManagerFeignClient = authManagerFeignClient;
    }
    public static class Config {}
    @Override
    public GatewayFilter apply(Config config) {
        return ((exchange, chain)->{            
            ServerHttpRequest httpRequest = null;           
                        if (routeValidator.isSecured.test(exchange.getRequest())) {
if (!exchange.getRequest().getHeaders().containsKey(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION)) {
throw new RuntimeException("Missing authorization header");}                
String authHeader = exchange.getRequest().getHeaders().get(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION).get(0);       //it's a token
if (authHeader != null && authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
authHeader = authHeader.substring(7);}
try {
jwtUtil.validateToken(authHeader);
String username = jwtUtil.extractUsername(authHeader);
List<String> roles = authManagerFeignClient.getRolesByUsername(username);
String rolesAsString = String.join(",", roles);
httpRequest = exchange.getRequest().mutate().header("loggedInUser", jwtUtil.extractUsername(authHeader)).header("loggedInUserRoles", rolesAsString).build();} catch (Exception e) {throw new RuntimeException("!!Unauthorized access to application!!");}
}
return chain.filter(exchange.mutate().request(httpRequest).build());
});
))

RouteValidator:
@Component
public class RouteValidator {
public static final List<String> openApiEndpoints = List.of("/api/auth/v1/register","/api/auth/v1/token","/eureka","/api-docs");
public Predicate<ServerHttpRequest> isSecured = request -> openApiEndpoints.stream().noneMatch(uri -> request.getURI().getPath().contains(uri));
}

JwtUtil:
@Component
public class JwtUtil {
public static final String SECRET = "............";
public void validateToken(final String token) {Jwts.parserBuilder().setSigningKey(getSignKey()).build().parseClaimsJws(token);}
private Key getSignKey() {
byte[] keyBytes = Decoders.BASE64.decode(SECRET);
return Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(keyBytes);}
public String extractUsername(String token) {
return extractClaim(token, Claims::getSubject);
}
public <T> T extractClaim(String token, Function<Claims, T> claimsResolver) {
final Claims claims = extractAllClaims(token);
return claimsResolver.apply(claims);
}
private Claims extractAllClaims(String token) {
return Jwts.parserBuilder().setSigningKey(getSignKey()).build().parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();}    
}

Auth_Manager_service:
@FeignClient(name = "Auth-Authentication-Manager", path = "api/auth/v1")
public interface Auth_Manager_Service {
@GetMapping("/getRolesByUsername")
public List<String> getRolesByUsername(@RequestParam("username") String username);
}

based on all this info how come in my postman when I am trying API "http://localhost:8084/api/auth/v1/getRolesByUsername?username=Raj" along with JWT bearer authorization, I keep getting 403 error?
When I am hitting the API in postman not even sysout or logger info in getting display for /getRolesByUsername.

anybody??anything??

Thanks for the A2A.
@A_B  : I have gone through both of the microservices code and seems in RouteValidator in the line :
public static final List openApiEndpoints = List.of("/api/auth/v1/register","/api/auth/v1/token","/eureka","/api-docs");
just add "/api/auth/v1/"
public static final List openApiEndpoints = List.of("/api/auth/v1/","/api/auth/v1/register","/api/auth/v1/token","/eureka","/api-docs");
As 403 forbidden error indicates : A 403 Forbidden Error occurs when you do not have permission to access a web page or something else on a web server
I hope you are aware of this error code , since the request can't even  hit the controller itself thus in sysout or logger info you are not getting display for /getRolesByUsername.
For your reference please check for the error code: https://www.howtogeek.com/357785/what-is-a-403-forbidden-error-and-how-can-i-fix-it/
